# XPath Expression For Selecting All Children Nodes Without Decendents Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

So I am using XPath in my Java application to parse an xml file. The file format is as follows:

```
<RootNode>
    <Node1>Value 1</Node1>
    <Node2>
        <Node2-1>
            <Node2-1-1>Value 2.1.1</Node2-1-1>
        </Node2-1>
    </Node2>
    <Node3>Value 3</Node3>
</RootNode>
```

I am trying to grab only Node1 and Node3 in a general way. With the RootNode context, I have tried:

```
child::[text()]
*/text()
*/node()
*
```

* gets me the closest but grabs Node2. How can get just single value nodes and ignore nodes with decedents?

Comment: is Value 1 a descendant of "Node1"? if so, should Node1 be excluded?

Comment: Value 1 is a string value inside of Node1. I think, at least in the few Java tests I have done, it counts as a text node, but I want to be able to retrieve the whole node including the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in xpath tester online and it worked:

```
RootNode/node()[not(*)]
```

Comment: This worked for me with one small modification. Since I had the RootNode context already in my application, I did not need to specify the "RootNode/" portion. I only needed "node()[not(*)]".

Comment: As a side not for those using the Java XPath parser, other "text" nodes will be retrieved as well, but filtering by Node.ELEMENT_NODE on node.type() will get just the ones your interested in.